# Recursive function : where am I wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Code :

```
isDomLoaded = $(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (renderFinished) {
            renderSocial(fotoProssima);
        } else {
            isDomLoaded();
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

it says `isDomLoaded is not a function`

Comment: maybe there is some context i am missing, but why are you passing a function declaration as an argument to a $ function, then assigning the value **that** returns to isDomLoaded?

Comment: Because you're casting it to a jQuery object...

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Couldn't you just use `$(function(){...});`? The function will only be called when the DOM is fully loaded...

Comment: @Shmiddty : DOM, CSS and JS, not image... that's different...

Comment: So add an onload event to the image? Still much cleaner.

Comment: Did any of those answers work out for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thats because it isn't a function. It is a jQuery object.

What you need might be:

```
isDomLoaded = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (renderFinished) {
            renderSocial(fotoProssima);
        } else {
            isDomLoaded();
        }
    }, 300);
};
```

If you want to run it when the DOM is ready then do this after you declare the function:

```
$(window).load(isDomLoaded);
```

However, I think what you really need is to get rid of the isDomLoaded function and just use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    renderSocial(fotoProssima);
});
```

Comment: Uhm...so how can I call that function, executing it the first time?

Comment: @markzzz Define a function? Right now you're executing the function on DOM ready. If you want a function, define a function.

Comment: @markzzz When using the solution above it's simply: `isDomLoaded()` inside a `document.ready`-event…

Comment: Man, it's truly astonishing how many people think jQuery is a distinct *language*.

Comment: use $(document).ready(isDomLoaded); to make it run when the DOM is finished loading

Comment: if you want to automatically execute a function too, do this: (a=function(){return true;})();

Comment: Well you can use $(window).load(isDomLoaded);

Comment: @markzzz: You should explain in detail what you want. If you want all resources, like images, on the page to be loaded, then you should use `window.onload = func...` or `$(window).load(func...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function isDomLoaded(){
    //code

    //recursive call
    isDomLoaded();
}
```